# Agregar la clausula GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Estoy trabajando con SQL Server 2014 Express Edition y tengo la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.ProductoCatalogoId AS Id, T.ProductoId,
CONCAT(T.Nombre, ' | ', T.TALLA, ' | ', C.COLOR) AS Descripcion, T.PrecioVenta, T.CATALOGO AS Nombre
FROM
(
    SELECT PC.ProductoCatalogoId, PC.ProductoId, P.Nombre, O.NombreOpcion AS TALLA, PC.PrecioVenta, C.Nombre AS CATALOGO
    FROM Productos AS P
    JOIN ProductoCatalogos AS PC ON P.ProductoId = PC.ProductoId
    JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId
    JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId
    JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EC.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
    JOIN Catalogos AS C ON PC.CatalogoId = C.CatalogoId
    WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%VESTIDO PIQUE%' AND EC.EspecificacionId = 5
) AS T
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT PC.ProductoCatalogoId, PC.ProductoId, P.Nombre, O.NombreOpcion AS COLOR, PC.PrecioVenta, C.Nombre AS CATALOGO
    FROM Productos AS P
    JOIN ProductoCatalogos AS PC ON P.ProductoId = PC.ProductoId
    JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId
    JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId
    JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EC.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
    JOIN Catalogos AS C ON PC.CatalogoId = C.CatalogoId
    WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%VESTIDO PIQUE%' AND EC.EspecificacionId = 2
) AS C
```

El resultado de esa consulta es la siguiente:
[image: consulta de selección]

Poniendo en el LIKE el nombre completo o casi completo(WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%VESTIDO PIQUE%') me da un resultado exacto como estamos viendo en la imagen.

¿Pero que sucede cuando solo pongo la palabra VESTIDO? me trae datos inconsistentes les muestro una imagen en donde pongo el nombre completo y luego solo le pongo la palabra VESTIDO.

[image: consulta de selección]

La manera que trabajo con ese formulario de búsqueda es de la siguiente manera:

1. Mando un like a la base de datos para que me traiga una serie de coincidencias.
2. Esas coincidencias la cargo en la grilla.
3. Cuando filtro en ese form de búsqueda estoy filtrando en el objeto DataGridView.

¿Como puedo solucionar el problema que tengo en lo expuesto lineas arriba?, me parece si le pongo un GROUP BY al final de la consulta a EC.ProductoCatalogoId pueda traer los datos consitentes así solo pongo la palabra VESTIDO.

El otro problema es que cuando agrego el GROUP BY al final de la consulta me pide que agregue todos los campos que están en la consulta de selección.

[image: productocatalogo]

El modelo que tengo es el siguiente, tengo una Catálogo para poder vender y tengo que ingresar los productos al catálogo, los productos van en ProductoCatalogo hay productos que tienen especificaciones y productos que no tienen especificaciones.

Cuando el producto tiene especificaciones se agrega en ProductoEspecificaciones, como decir la talla y el color, claro que antes se a debido de crear talla y color en Especificaciones la cual esta relacionada con Opciones en esta tabla van los colores(rojo, negro, amarillo, etc) y talla(s, m, l, xl, etc), entonces cuando un producto tiene especificaciones desde el Catalogo se le pone especificaciones de catalogo y ahí le registro que talla y colores lleva.

Se complica solo cuando hago la búsqueda de productos que tienen especificaciones(se complica en el sentido que para que me traiga las especificaciones exactas tengo que poner el nombre completo del producto, mientras no haga eso como por ejemplo pongo vestido y en la db tengo varios productos que comienzan con vestido las especificaciones no son exactas hasta que vaya completando el nombre del producto).

Veo que si no pongo el nombre completo no dará el resultado exacto.

NOTA: En VESTIDO PIQUE no existe en mi base de datos el color amarillo y verde, cuando pongo solo VESTIDO.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos!

Comment: La manera en la que _deberías_ de agrupar, depende completamente del resultado que quieres obtener. Sugiero que añadas una muestra de los datos de entrada y del resultado que esperas obtener con esos datos.

Comment: @jachguate Ya aclare mi pregunta, cualquier duda me lo haces saber por si necesitas mas información.

Comment: Sigo sin ver la _inconsistencia_. Sé que es claro para vos, pero no has explicado lo que esperas encontrar ni qué hay en cada tabla. Por favor lee [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate si hago los filtros directamente en la base de datos no hay problema funciona perfectamente, solo que le estaría pegando al performace de la db.

Answer (score 2):

Los CROSS son mucho a muchos...cambia por inner join...mas o menos quedaria asi

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.ProductoCatalogoId AS Id, T.ProductoId,
CONCAT(T.Nombre, ' | ', T.TALLA, ' | ', C.COLOR) AS Descripcion, T.PrecioVenta, T.CATALOGO AS Nombre
FROM
(
    SELECT PC.ProductoCatalogoId, PC.ProductoId, P.Nombre, O.NombreOpcion AS TALLA, PC.PrecioVenta, C.Nombre AS CATALOGO
    FROM Productos AS P
    JOIN ProductoCatalogos AS PC ON P.ProductoId = PC.ProductoId
    JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId
    JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId
    JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EC.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
    JOIN Catalogos AS C ON PC.CatalogoId = C.CatalogoId
    WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%VESTIDO PIQUE%' AND EC.EspecificacionId = 5
) AS T
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PC.ProductoCatalogoId, PC.ProductoId, P.Nombre, O.NombreOpcion AS COLOR, PC.PrecioVenta, C.Nombre AS CATALOGO
    FROM Productos AS P
    JOIN ProductoCatalogos AS PC ON P.ProductoId = PC.ProductoId
    JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId
    JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId
    JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EC.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
    JOIN Catalogos AS C ON PC.CatalogoId = C.CatalogoId
    WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%VESTIDO PIQUE%' AND EC.EspecificacionId = 2
) AS C ON C.ProductoCatalogoId = T.ProductoCatalogoId
```